# SQL - select another row if the first select row returns empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am using **SQL server**.
I have the following table

```
Name   Number
A      123
B      456
C      789
D      000
```

I am given 2 names. I want to write a sql statement so that I can select check if the first given name exists in the table.

- If so, the sql returns the row with the first name.
- If not, it will check the second name. If the row with the second name is found, then
  return that row.
- If  both names not found, then return empty

For example,

- if 'A', 'C' are given , the sql statement should return the row with
  name 'A' only.
- if 'G', 'B' are given, it should check 'G' first but not found, then return the row with name 'B' because it is found.
- if 'X', 'Y' are given, then it should return empty row

What is the **most efficient** but generic SQL statement to achieve it? (What I mean by "generic" is that I want to write a sql statement that fits to most kinds of Retional SQL DB instead of just SQL server)

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I means return "no rows" when saying "empty row". I apologize for my incorrect wording.

Comment: How are this values "given"?, how do you order them?

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to do `where name in ('a', 'b')` order by ...` type thing and throw away the lines you don't want?

Comment: And why should your query return an empty row when there are no rows found? That doesn't make any sense at all to me.

Comment: @SeanLange Not sure about this, but maybe op meant "no rows" when saying "empty row"

Comment: Lamak got what I mean. "no rows" means"empty row". I apologize for my incorrect wording.

Comment: Maybe also this can help
Select top 1 row_number() Over (Order by name),name From Table where name in (@a,@b) order by name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without a `union all`:

```
select top 1 t.*
from table t
where name in (@name1, @name2)
order by (case when name = @name1 then 1 else 0 end) desc;
```

Comment: Don't you want the else to be 2? The way it is coded here it would have name2 at the top.

Comment: This seems to be easiest way for me to do it.

Comment: @SeanLange He is using `desc` this does the trick, no typo I guess.

Comment: Or `ORDER BY NULLIF(name, @name1)`. Concise but obscure. But concise.

Answer (score 5):

```
select top 1 number from (

select 1 pos, number where name =@a
union all
select 2, number where name= @b)
order by pos
```

Comment: You should give the sort order column an alias and order by the alias. Ordering by ordinal position is very dangerous.

Comment: @SeanLange corrected, but never heard of that danger. Any reference? Thanks

Comment: It isn't a reference thing. Consider what happens if you order by ordinal position and somebody else comes along and changes the order of the columns in the select statement. Suddenly your result is in the wrong order. On a simple query like this it would be obvious but on longer queries it can be a real problem. As always, it is better to be explicit instead of taking a shortcut that will bit you in the rear later.

Comment: @Horaciux https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: Alas there is a link for it. Thanks @Lamak. I should have known that Aaron would have an article about that.

Comment: I will also flag this answer as a useful one.